# Backbone - this.$el vs $(this.el)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, el

I've been using `this.$el` all over my backbone app like so:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template);
},
```

then I saw code online that uses:

```
render: function() {
    var dict = this.model.toJSON();
    var html = this.template(dict);
    $(this.el).append(html);
}
```

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: The docs are pretty clear on what [`$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) is. Someone using `$(this.el)` learned Backbone in the old days (or learned from a tutorial based on an old version), that's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call $(this.el), your just keep executing the [jquery selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) to get the same jquery object.  '$el' is the cached version of $(this.el)